# How to constraint two buttons to be equidistant from the vertical center

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm fairly experienced with using constraints, but up till now everthing I've arranged has been aligned along some vertical or horizonal center.
I've spent all morning sifting through past questions and tutorials but am still unable to arrange these two buttons, it ought to be simple, but I can't find the vital missing piece

[image]

XCode's own suggested constraints are just off their head on drugs, and trying to add them myself where it is going wrong is if I set all the constraints up for one screen size, then when viewing them in another they are not centered:

[image]

How do I add a constraint so that the buttons are aligned on either side of the vertical center?

Comment: I would put an invisible small UIView in the horizontal center, then assign horizontal spacing equally to both of button.

Comment: I considered that, but thought this must be such a common occurrance that XCode would have something built in to deal with it. But apparently not?

Comment: Put them inside stackview or uiview, if it is uiview you need to add constraints, in stackview you don't .

Comment: as @Dasem mentioned, nested UIView or StackView could be a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gereon's answer is better than @conarch's, IMHO, because spacer views are almost never the right approach. I have a third approach, though, that I find to be more robust than @Gereon's because it doesn't rely on hard-coded constants.

1. Enclose both buttons in a `UIView` (**Editor -> Embed In -> View**).
2. Constrain the **left button**'s **left edge** to the **left edge** of the **parent view**.
3. Constrain the **right button**'s **right edge** to the **right edge** of the **parent view**.
4. Constrain the **left button**'s **right edge** to the **right button**'s **left edge** and give it the desired spacing constant.
5. Constrain the tops and bottoms and/or heights as you see fit.
6. Align the **horizontal center** of the **parent view** to *its* **parent view**'s **horizontal center**.

Comment: I respect your opinion, but I think "better" is subjective as it really depends on what the user ultimately wants to accomplish.  I think all 3 of the current answers here are viable and offer useful approaches to add to the OP's pool of knowledge.  e.g. Your answer might be exactly what the OP needs, but it won't always symmetrically space the buttons on different devices and orientations (they'll always be exactly "x" apart).

Answer (score 1):

Start by setting the "align horizontally in container" constraints. Once you've done that, you can modifiy the `constant` of both "Align center X" constraints to add an offset, e.g. -10 for the left and 10 for the right button.

Answer (score 0):

A few ways to do this, but a common trick that could help (if not now, then later) is to use "spacer" views.  In your case, you could...

1. Put 3 hidden UIView objects on the canvas: One to the left of the first button, one to the right of the second button, and one between the 2 buttons.
2. Use constraints to make those 3 views always have equal width.
3. Pin your first button b/n the first 2 spacer views, and pin the second button b/n your last 2 spacer views. (i.e. leading/trailing are 0)